# How to display my string which changes often in the app by using placeholder using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, string

I'm trying to build an app where the rpm is extracted from a Bluetooth OBD2 sensor.

I am able to extract the rpm successfully and even show it in the log cat.

When I successfully connect to the Bluetooth OBD2, it is supposed to show the rpm value as we can see in the strings.xml. But instead, it shows RPM : %1$s. This placeholder is supposed to be replaced by the formattedRPM variable from Main activity.java.

Here are the sufficient and relevant codes.

This is a part of my mainactivity.java where the RPM value is extracted using the OBD2 and assigned to formattedRPM.

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                        if (socket.isConnected()) {
                            rpmCommand.run(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
                            // TODO: Handle commands result
                            String rpmValue = rpmCommand.getFormattedResult();
                            String formattedRPM = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.formattedRPM), rpmValue);
                            // Update the UI with the RPM value
                            //String strformattedRPM = String.format(c.getResources().getString(R.string.formattedRPM),"rpmValue");
                            Log.d("OBD2", "Updating rpmTextView with value: " + formattedRPM);
                            runOnUiThread(() -> rpmTextView.setText(formattedRPM));
                        } else {
                            // Handle the case when the socket is closed
                            // For example, reconnect or show an error message
                            Log.e("OBD2", "Socket is closed");
                            break;  // Exit the loop if the socket is closed
                        }

                } catch (NoDataException e) {
                    Log.e("OBD2", "No data available for RPM");
                    // Handle the NoDataException as needed (e.g., log, show a message, etc.

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("OBD2", "Error reading from Bluetooth socket: " + e.getMessage());
                    // Handle the IOException (e.g., close the socket, retry, etc.)
                    closeBluetoothSocket(socket);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showStatus("Failed to connect to OBD-II");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

This is my strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="btn_choose_device">Choose Bluetooth Device</string>
    <string name="connection_status">Connection Status: Not Connected</string>
    <string name="ecu_status">ECU Status: Not Connected</string>
    <string name="formattedRPM">RPM : %1$s</string>
</resources>
```

This is a part of my main_activity.xml

```
<!-- RPM Value -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rpmTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/formattedRPM"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvEcuStatus"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

How do I get the rpm(basically whatever is showing in the logcat) to show in the app replacing the placeholder? Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I think you can use DataBinding to show value in TextView.

Comment: In your XML, you have set the text to your string.resource value. Have you tried removing that and seeing what is shown?

Comment: use databinding and declare a variable in xml and initialize the variable in your main activity or fragment (wherever you are getting the value you want). This will solve your problem

Comment: Is it possible to not use DataBinding but utilize placeholder instead? Because I am still relatively new and I am trying to look into DataBinding